# Commercial SRAM with separate power supply for the core and peripheral?

Tags: integrated-circuit, memory, sram

Are there commercial SRAMs available with a separate power supply for the core transistors (6T) and a separate supply for the remaining circuitry such as the sense amps, write drivers, etc?

I believe the voltages are usually tied together but wanted to know if there are ICs with a separate pin for each. Just to be clear, this is *NOT* a dual rail sram. A dual-rail sram would have two different power supplies but it uses an internal level shifter and both are delivered through the same external pin.

Comment: I'm struggling to see any use for this, though I guess there could be something with low-power stuff...

Comment: Why would you need this? For reduce power usage by turning out the "remaining circuitry" in those moments when you just need do keep the data, and don't need to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There's no point. The vast majority of the transistors in the SRAM are in the core. If the chip uses a manufacturing process that results in low-leakage transistors there, then the tiny fraction of additional transistors in the periphery are low-leakage, too.

And most SRAM chips turn off things like sense amplifiers whenever the chip is disabled through the CS input anyway.